# What is the ruling in seeing women naked in foreign countries beaches?

Tags: halal-haram, women, men, awrah

I live in Canada. And I go out with my friend every weekend. Mostly we go to the beach and enjoy the day. I have not feel awkward but now I think this should be cleared. Is it halal if we go to the beach in foreign countries. I have a female friend and she also go with us in weekends. We go covering our bodies but no one absolutely no one is covered at the beach. The women are in their bikinis which reveals their private parts. And men are also not covered. So can anybody tell me what is the ruling on this. Should we go or not. I means that we are seeing a woman naked and our female friend is seeing a man naked though they are Non-Muslims but they are also humans?

Answer (score 1):

It is Absolutely Haram.

Brother, One of the distinguishing features of Islam is the rulings on Modesty. Islam teaches us modesty and is strongly against shamelessness.

Prophet Muhammmad (SAW) says:
'The Iman has 70 departments and haya (modesty) is one of them'

In Quran Allah says:

> 'Tell the believers to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts, etc.). That is purer for them. Verily, Allah is All-Aware of what they do.'

[24:30]

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum
It's haram my brother.
In such situation satan wants to provoke you.
Say oh Allah you are my creator you are my only protector.
Oh Allah Protect me  from all haram.